# Sequence of print statement in fork() syatem call

Tags: operating-system, fork, computer-science, system-calls

To get a a better understanding of fork() system call , i am randomly playng between fork() and print statement but got stuck in one such code ,the code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   printf("\n my process id %d \n",getpid());
   pid_t pid1=fork();
   printf("\nPID:=%d fork returned %d\n",getpid(),pid1);
   pid_t pid2=fork();
   printf("\nPID:=%d fork returned %d\n",getpid(),pid2);
   pid_t pid3=fork();
   printf("\nPID:=%d fork returned %d\n",getpid(),pid3);
   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output obtained-:

[image: output]

I am not able to get the print sequence it is following.Only thing i am getting is that first the process with PID 5079 is executing ,and for all the fork() system call,it is returning child PID to the parent  process.I am not getting the further sequence.

Comment: Do you know what does fork do ? how it works ? its return value ?
It seems you just used it without really thinking. Once a new process is spawned, there's no guarantee who runs first. So you can expect any output really. Next is up to you: look what fork() sys call return value is.

Answer (score 0):

The fork() might seem a little confusing at first, but its actually pretty simple. What it does is copy the current process into a new process in another memory location (copy everything, its data, code, current instruction, ...).

So we started with a process with pid = 5079, when we got to the fork call, a child process with pid = 5080 was created, and it has the same code of the parent process.

```
 // Parent Process //                    // Child Process //
 #include<stdio.h>                       #include<stdio.h> 
 #include<unistd.h>                      #include<unistd.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>                      #include<stdlib.h>
 int main()                              int main()
 {                                       {
    printf("\...                            printf("\...
    pid_t pid1=fork();                      pid_t pid1=fork(); 
    printf("\nPI...    //Next line//        printf("\nPI...    //Next line//
    pid_t pid2=fork();                      pid_t pid2=fork();
    printf("\nPID:=...                      printf("\nPID:=...
    pid_t pid3=fork();                      pid_t pid3=fork();
    printf("\nPID:=...                      printf("\nPID:=...
    return 0;                               return 0;
 }                                        }
```

before we continue following the code, the return value of the fork call is as follows: inside the process that called the fork(), the return value is the pid of the child process (pid1 variable in Parent Process = 5080), and inside the child process, the output is 0 (pid1 variable in Child Process = 0).

So the print statement after the fork will be executed by the Parent Process and the Child Process with different getpid() value and different pid1 values, the parent has getpid() = 5079, and pid1 = child's pid = 5080 (you can see this in the third line of the output). The child will make its own print statement, with getpid() = 5080 and pid1 = 0, you can see this in the 8th line of the output, but why the 8th line!!!

The operating system schedules the process, that is, it decides which process the CPU will work on and for how long. so it seems that the OS decided that the parent process (pid = 5079) should run for a little longer, and left the child process (pid = 5080) waiting for the CPU to execute its instructions.

So process 5079 went on with the next fork, creating a new child process with pid = 5081. Then it printed what we expect in the third line, then it went on to the last fork creating process 5082, printing what we would expect in the forth line, then terminating (process 5079 terminated, leaving 5080,5081,5082 waiting, and Adopted by the OS, they need to have a parent, but this isn't important to the output).

Now that 5079 terminated, we have 3 processes waiting in the memory for the CPU to work them. The operating system must decide which process to run, and it seems to have choose the process that is closest to terminate, which is process 5082, let's look at the remaining instructions for each process:

```
  // process 5082 //      // process 5081 //     // process 5080 //
  printf("\nP...          printf("\nP...         printf("\nP...
  return 0;               pid_t pid3=fork();     pid_t pid2=fork();
                          printf("\nP...         printf("\nP...
                          return 0;              pid_t pid3=fork();
                                                 printf("\nP...
                                                 return 0;
```

Why is this the remaining code? any process created by a fork in some other process will start executing after that fork statement like we have seen earlier. so process 5082 printed line 5 then terminated (its value of pid3 = 0 because it is a child of 5079). After terminating of 5082, 5081 took the CPU, and it printed line 6, then created process 5085 as we can see in line 6 (why not 5083 in order? maybe the OS created some process during the execution of your code).

after printing line 6 process 5081 has terminated. Now we have 5080, and 5085 in the memory. you should now be able to follow the pattern, 5080 was selected to run, creating 5086 and 5087 then terminating. then 5085 ran, followed by 5087, which only had the print statement in the end, both then terminated, and we were left with 5086 which printed, made the last fork creating 5088, then terminated as did 5088 after its print.

Operating systems is a fascinating field, its fun to go beyond the system calls, if you are interested in this I would recommend this book, it is what I studied in college:
[https://www.amazon.com/Operating-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0470128720](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470128720)